# Use property value in select query in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Model `Event` -> id, guests_count, status.
Model `Guest` -> id, event_id, confirmed.

I need something like this:

```
Event::where('status', 'opened')->whereNotIn('id', $nId)
                        ->has('guests', '<' , XXX)
                        ->get();
```

Instead `XXX` I need to use `guests_count` value - different value for each event - is this possible?

I'm trying to get all not filled events (count of `guests` relation < `guests_count`).

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: `guests_count` is a column having different values for different `Event` in the database table?

Comment: @SaiyanPrince it's number of max guests. Different values for diff `Event`. If number of guests (relations) is equal to `guests_count` and all guests are confirmed (invitations), `status` is updated to Full. So there might be case when number if guests is equal to `guests_count` but `status` is not Full (when all invitations aren't confirmed yet) - so I can't simply search by `status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Event::where('status', 'opened')->whereNotIn('id', $nId)
    ->withCount('guests as count')
    ->having('guests_count', '>', DB::raw('`count`'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Just small edit - `withCount('guests as count')` is adding `_count` after that name, so 'correct' is `->having('guests_count', '>', DB::raw('count_count'))`

Comment: I only tested the code in 5.6. I looked at the source, this behavior was changed in Laravel 5.5: In 5.5+ the alias is just `count`.

Answer (score 0):

did you need this ?

```
Event::select([DB::raw('count(guests) as count'),'id'])
    ->where('status','opened')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $nId)
    ->groupBy('guests')
    ->having('count','>',10)
    ->get();
```

sql output

```
select count(guests) as count, `id` from `event` where `status` = 'opened' and `id` not in ([1,2,3]) group by `guests` having `count` > 10
```

Comment: Why is there `->having('count','>',10)`? This number is always different for different Event, in one Event it is 50, in another 300, I have to use this specific value in query. So if `guests_count` is 10, I need include this event in collection only if count of guests relation is < 10. If these 2 values are equal, I don't want this in collection

Comment: Event 1 - guests_count = 10; count of guests relation = 7; `include in collection`

Event 2 - guests_count = 55; count of guests relation = 42; `include in collection`

Event 3 - guests_count = 15; count of guests relation = 15; `don't include`